# outcome display not showing on bargraph

Tags: r

I want to display my binary outcome (yes/no disease) in relation to comorbidities(3 levels) on a bar graph however the outcome is not displayed

```
library(tidyverse)
# Convert disease to a factor
data10$disease <- factor(data10$disease, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("No Disease",     "Disease"))

# Create a bar graph
ggplot(data10, aes(x = Comorbidities, fill = disease)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  labs(x = "Comorbidities", y = "Count", title = "Bar Graph: Disease vs  Comorbidities") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("No Disease" = "blue", "Disease" = "red")) +  # Use specific     colors
  theme_minimal()
```

This is the display I get: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuQdS.png)

Comment: We don't have your data, but I'm guessing the problem is that `data10$disease` doesn't start out as ones and zeros, but rather "yes" and "no", in which case your conversion to factor will leave the entire column as `NA`. You would need to do something like `data10$disease <- factor(as.integer(data10$disease == "yes"), levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("No disease", "Disease"))`. Alternatively, leave the column as it is and just change the `labels` in `scale_fill_manual`. If that doesn't help, please post some reproducible data using `dput(data10)`